# How to change the font size of bar code via ZPL?

Tags: printing, barcode, zpl

Is it possible to change the text of bar code on ZPL?

e.g.
http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=24&width=25.5&height=12&units=mm&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5EBY3%2C5%2C200%0A%5EFO55%2C30%0A%5EBC%0A%5EFD1234567890ABCDEF%0A%5EFS%0A%0A%5EXZ

```html
^XA

^BY3,5,200
^FO55,30
^BC
^FD1234567890ABCDEF
^FS

^XZ
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to change the text interpretation within a bar-code in ZPL, but you can hide it and put in something of your own.

```
^XA
^BY3,5,200
^FO55,30
^BC,,N
^FD1234567890ABCDEF
^FS
^FO55,250
^A0N,20,20
^FD1234567890
^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 1):

1) It depends on the firmware version, please see:
https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/code_128.htm#Printing%20the%20interpretation%20line%20in%20a%20different%20font

2) Unfortunately, method of manual text printing has a restriction - it's impossible to center this text below the barcode, which can have different width...

UPDATE
Unfortunately, my short test shows, that even when we use "automatic interpretation line", but with font change (as described in my link), it also shifts label to the left. Probably, nice center alignment is possible only for the "very standard" font :(